# I have a problem with putExtra from adapter when I click to textview in the adapter I just send Arraylist data to detail but it show error

Tags: java, android

E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: uz.asror.tourism, PID: 6366
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{uz.asror.tourism/uz.asror.tourism.view.PlaceDetail}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.util.ArrayList.get(int)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3922)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.util.ArrayList.get(int)' on a null object reference
at uz.asror.tourism.view.PlaceDetail.onCreate(PlaceDetail.java:50)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8595)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8573)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1456)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3764)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3922) 
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)

[It's adapter class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADLyQ.png)[It's detailActivty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZmaT.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there are a few issues in your code. Let's break it down step by step.

Firstly, when you use putExtra to pass data to another activity, make sure you are sending the correct type of data. In your case, it seems you are trying to send a single string, not an ArrayList.

```
intent.putExtra("data", listdata.get(0).toString());
```

But when you try to retrieve it, you're expecting a StringArrayList. Instead, you should get a single string from the Intent.

```
String receivedData = intent.getStringExtra("data");
```

Then, when you're setting the data to your TextViews and other views, ensure you're using the correct index for the data you received.

```
placeName.setText(receivedData);
```

Regarding the image, if you're trying to set an image resource based on the received data, make sure that the data you're receiving is the resource ID (an integer). If you're trying to set an image using an integer value, you can use setImageResource() directly without parsing.

```
imageViewDetail.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(receivedDataList.get(1)));
```